# Laravel get mimeType from uploaded image

Tags: php, laravel

I am using jQuery file uploader to upload a resized image, convert it to blob and save it as blob into a DB.

For the database I also need to save the mimeType, which I see in the request, which I receive, but I dont understand how to get the mimeType value.

The code to send the image:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("_token", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
formData.append("user_id_val", $('.user-general-i').data('userid'));

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", data.files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://localhost.eu/home/create_comment_images");

request.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        console.log('success');
    } else {
        console.log(request.status);
    }
};

request.send(formData);
```

Code on the server:

```
public function create_comment_images(Request $data) {
    \Log::info($data);
    try {  

        $path = $data->userfile;

        $logo = file_get_contents($path);

        $base64 = base64_encode($logo);

        return ['success' => true];                                 
    } catch (\Exception $e) {  
        return ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];   
    } 

    return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Something went wrong'];
}
```

The log info shows me this:

```
array (
  '_token' => 'QxOqetFU2Re6fwe442vksGNnvV0C88v8dcrFpAp',
  'user_id_val' => '568092',
  'userfile' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'Unbenannt.png',
     'mimeType' => 'image/png',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

I am almost there, I need the get the mimeType information from the array.

I tried:

```
$data->userfile->mime_content_type
$data->userfile->mimeType
$data->userfile['mimeType']
$data->userfile[0]['mimeType']
```

Nothing works. Any ideas how to extract that information?

Comment: just a guess `$data->userfile->getMimeType()` give it a try

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel you can use the intervention library. This library is very powerfull you can change the format, resize and do all kind of stuff.

Here a basic example..

```
// read image from temporary file
$img = Image::make($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

// get or sets the mime type.
$mimeType = $img::mime(); 

// save image
$img->save('foo/bar.jpg');

// Get image as string.
$string = base64_encode($img->encode('jpg'));
```

[Intervention Reference](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction)

Comment: Website not reachable for me

Comment: I just verified and is working on my side this is the full link. http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 0):

To get the mimetype from the uploaded file header, you can call `getMimeType()` on the `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` class.

```
$uploadedFile = $data->file('userfile');// or 
$mimeType = $uploadedFile->getMimeType()
```

Comment: I had tried this, it had not worked, but I found a workaround. I set the needed information with JS: `formData.append("userfile_name", data.files[0].name);
formData.append("userfile_mime", data.files[0].type);`

Comment: what about `$data->userfile[0]->getMimeType()` ?

Comment: @Roman it's bad practice to get the MimeType from the client side. you expose yourself to some security issue. Try getting the file from `request()->file()` method